# Object can not access in angularjs ng-model?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I want to display client id and country based on user selecting client from client list,I can be display entire selected object but can not display selected client details.

```
<label class="control-label red">Client</label>
                {{selectedClient}}
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedClient">
                    <option ng-repeat="client in clients" value="{{client.id}}">{{client.name}}</option>
                </select>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addressModel"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                    &nbsp;{{selectedClient.id}},{{selectedClient.address_info.country}}
                </a>
```

Here `selectedClient` is displaying accordingly selecting from select-box,but `selectedClient.id` and `selectedClient.address_info.country` is not displaying even though they holding some values.

output of selectedClient is,

```
{
    "id": 127,
    "payment_terms_id": null,
    "name": "Shihabs company",
    "note": null,
    "created_by": 0,
    "updated_by": null,
    "deleted_by": null,
    "created_at": "2015-03-09 10:32:31",
    "updated_at": "2015-03-09 10:32:31",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "status": 1,
    "payment_term": null,
    "address_info": {
        "id": 54,
        "client_id": 127,
        "street": null,
        "city": null,
        "pobox": null,
        "country": null,
        "phone": null,
        "work_phone": null,
        "mobile": null,
        "email": null,
        "website": null,
        "billing_street": null,
        "billing_city": null,
        "billing_pobox": null,
        "billing_country": null,
        "billing_phone": null,
        "billing_work_phone": null,
        "billing_mobile": null,
        "billing_email": null,
        "shipping_street": null,
        "shipping_city": null,
        "shipping_pobox": null,
        "shipping_country": null,
        "shipping_phone": null,
        "shipping_work_phone": null,
        "shipping_mobile": null,
        "shipping_email": null,
        "created_by": null,
        "updated_by": null,
        "deleted_by": null,
        "created_at": "2015-03-09 10:32:31",
        "updated_at": "2015-03-09 10:32:31",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "status": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show example selectedClient, ie the rendered output of {{selectedClient}}

Comment: @UlukBiy updated question with selectedClient output..

Comment: if selectedClient is an array of objects, your code won't work as is. Can you present all output.

Comment: got answer.. thank you for the effort..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way to bind select option

```
 <select  ng-model="selectedClient" ng-options="client.name for client in 
 clients"></select>
```

Comment: how can I use `ng-selected` on this expression, any idea?